# TFS 2008 Disk Usage

Tags: tfs

From within TFS 2008, is there a way to view the disk space taken up on the server by a project (or by all projects)?  Or is this something that can only be done by looking directly at the underlying database?

Comment: If you want to provide more details, I'm interested to know what data you are wanting to know and why.  We (Microsoft) are currently planning out the next version of TFS.  Do you want to know the space occupied by Version Control, Work Item Tracking, Build?  Do you want to include the build drops in that figure?  What about the data in any associated SharePoint portal? And why it is important to you to know per project rather than per server or per "project collection" - which is an isolated set of team projects in TFS 2010.

Comment: Just interested in the disk usage by the separate projects (mainly for future hardware requirements).  A breakdown of the component parts would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a good way to easily do this on a per project basis (including Version Control, Work Item Tracking, Build and Project Portal data).  The data is all stored in the various SQL Server databases but there is no separation at the project level showing you how much that data ends up costing you in disk space - you'd need to sum up the totals of the various databases on disk to give you that number.

The following blog post from Brian Harry might help you get close to the data you need for TFS 2008

- [TFS Statistics](http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/archive/2009/10/23/tfs2010-sql-queries-for-tfs-statistics.aspx)

The way that stuff is stored in TFS 2010 is very different, see [Grant Holliday's blog post for a set of queries that work against the TFS 2010 database](http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/archive/2009/10/23/tfs2010-sql-queries-for-tfs-statistics.aspx).